# What is the typical chemical composition of Earth's mass gain

Tags: meteorite, earth-system

Consider this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mass#Variation

To quote:

> The main factor in mass gain is in-falling material, cosmic dust, meteors, etc. are the most significant contributors to Earth's increase in mass. The sum of material is estimated to be 37000 to 78000 tons annually

I would like to know, if there is an estimate of chemical composition of mass. That is , I am looking for a categorization of this mass in x% Carbon, y% Silicon, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: There's gain and loss. The gain-part would probably follow meteorite composition. Maybe relevant: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16688/is-earth-getting-heavier-or-lighter/16725#16725

Comment: @Earthworm of course, but my question is the bulk chemical composition of the incoming meteor and cosmic dust

Comment: Then just look up what ordinary and carbonaceous chondrites are made of, and you're set to go..